# How to disable the default behaviour of a MFC link control?

Tags: mfc, hyperlink, controls

I am using a MFC link control in my dialog based application,and I add an event handler of BN_CLICKED for it, hoping that it could do something for me, however, when i click on it, it just does nothing at all(when i don't set the url of it, when i set the url, it will jump to that url), my event handler is not triggered. So, how to disable its default "jump" behaviour and trigger my handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclassing `CMFCLinkCtrl` and adding an `ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN` event handler seems to work.

You can then choose whether or not to call `CMFCLinkCtrl::OnLButtonDown`.

```
class CMyLinkCtrl : public CMFCLinkCtrl {
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMyLinkCtrl)
public:
    CMyLinkCtrl();
    virtual ~CMyLinkCtrl();
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CMyLinkCtrl, CMFCLinkCtrl)

CMyLinkCtrl::CMyLinkCtrl() {
}

CMyLinkCtrl::~CMyLinkCtrl() {
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyLinkCtrl, CMFCLinkCtrl)
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyLinkCtrl::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
    static bool bDisabled = false;
    if(bDisabled) {
        MessageBox(_T("Link is disabled"));
    } else {
        CMFCLinkCtrl::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
    }
    bDisabled = !bDisabled;
}
```

Comment: thank you. subclassing works! But there is a small problem, when i add the line 'AfxMessageBox(_T("you clicked"));' in the default OnLButtonDown handler, it popuped when i click, but it didn't jump, but i didn't comment out the invocation of the default CMFCLinkCtrl::OnLButtonDown handler.

Comment: CMFCLinkCtrl is probably waiting for another message after LBUTTONDOWN that is not firing when your message box takes focus. Try using Spy++ (from Visual Studio) to compare the sequence of messages sent to the LinkCtrl.

Comment: I wanted a thing as simple as to make my link control to process `ON_BN_CLICKED`. To do it, I simply derived a class and set `m_bDefaultClickProcess` to `TRUE` on its constructor. It just works fine! :)